# Backbase Integration with Spring Microservices

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, microservices, backbase-portal, backbase

We want to create middle tier using Spring Microservices which works as communication bridge between Backbase and Finxact. Backbase hosted by another vendor so do not have full control of it. We only need to focus on our Integration layer.

What are the configuration steps we need to follow for?

1. Making communication between Backbase and our middle tier
2. Authenticating request coming from Backbase for serving proper response

Answer (score 0):

do you have access to Backbase Community? The how-to implementation on how to build an integration service can be found here: https://community.backbase.com/documentation/cxs/latest/integration_services_extend